# Data is not appearing on HTML... it is showing empty instead

Tags: python, django

I have created a Database and also create a form to add data in it.
But when I try to show the data on html it shows nothing.
My Model is

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    bankname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    acctitle=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    branchname=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    branchcode=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    adddate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bankname
```

My Views

```
def add_bank(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        bankname=request.POST.get('bankname')
        acctitle=request.POST.get('acctitle')
        city=request.POST.get('city')
        branchname=request.POST.get('branchname')
        branchcode=request.POST.get('branchcode')

        data=Bank(bankname=bankname,acctitle=acctitle,city=city,branchname=branchname, branchcode=branchcode)
        data.save();
    return render(request, 'add_bank.html')

        
def add_amount(request):

    banks= Bank.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'add_amount.html', {'banks':banks})
```

My Html for displaying data

```
<select name="banks" class="form-control custom-select">
                      <option value="">Bank:</option>
                      {% for bank in banks %}
                        <option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ banks.bankname }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                      
                    </select>
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzY1E.png)

I don't know where I'm making mistake

Comment: There is typo in `{{ banks.bankname }}`. Replace `banks` with `bank` inside option tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change `banks.bankname` to `bank.bankname` in this line:

```
<option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ banks.bankname }}</option>
```

To understand why this didn't result in an error, you can refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables).

Comment: Oops Thank You so much... But I'm facing one more issue. 
I'm adding one data but it is showing one more copy of same data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a for loop in which every item (object) of the banks model is referred to as a **bank** by you in a loop. So use **"bank.bankname"**.

eg.

```
<option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ bank.bankname }}</option>
```

Also, As the best practice try to use your table's **primary key** in value in the Option tag. This will help you for better reference to the particular data (tables object) in javascript for sending data to views.

eg.

```
<option value="{{ bank.banks_primary_key }}">{{ bank.bankname }}</option>
```

Comment: Oops Thank You so much... But I'm facing one more issue. 
I'm adding one data but it is showing one more copy of same data in the database.

Comment: Adnan, you are still using banks instead of bank (bank.bankname) in the HTML loop. And also read my updated answer.